# C++ template: How to put nontype constraints in compiling time

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have following template

```
template<unsigned char I, unsigned char F>
class FOO
{
   ....
}
```

In fact, I require (I >= F). If someone misuses

```
FOO<1, 2> a;
```

I hope to raise a compiling error. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way may be C++11's `static_assert`, which is similar to an `assert`, but checked at compile time:

```
template<unsigned char I, unsigned char F>
class FOO
{
    static_assert(I >= F, "I needs to be larger or equal to F");
    ...
};
```

Comment: `static_assert` is a declaration. It can appear in class scope.

Comment: @KennyTM Ah Ok, so I can just put it inside the class definition? nice, didn't know that (well, haven't used it largely yet, anyway).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have C++11, the good old array bounds trick works here too. Just put the following in the private section of your class:

```
static int const error_size = I >= F ? 1 : -1;
typedef char ERROR_I_must_not_be_less_than_F[error_size];
```

This will trigger a "negative array size" error whenever `I` is less than `F`.

Comment: Or just `typedef char ERROR_I_must_not_be_less_than_F[I-F];`